# Pin Allocation in Job Scheduling example in OptaPlanner

Tags: scheduling, allocation, optaplanner

I'm trying to pin Allocations start date in the Job Scheduling example of OptaPlanner. The issue comes from the fact that Allocation are defined by their delay from the previous Allocation. If I add the @PlanningPin annotation it will lock the delay but not the start date of the Allocation as the start date of previous ones can change. Is there an elegant way of doing this ?

For now I added a boolean pinned in the Allocation class which reduce the hardScore by as much as it is out of sync with the pinned start date (example: -5hard if the allocation start date is 5 units later than the pinned start date). It works well for simple examples but I don't know if it's an proper solution and it doesn't imply that the allocation will not move as it's only driven by score calculation.

I hope I made myself understandable. Thank you.

Comment: Can you explain the motivation for pinning the `startdate`? The `readyDate` specifies the earliest date a task can start. The `dueDate` specifies the latest date a task can start. Would it make sense to just put the `readyDate = startDate`?

Comment: I want users to be able to pin some jobs when they have been planned. When the scheduling is launched again I don't want these jobs to move. I don't know about these `readyDate` and `dueDate`.